# ROS Answers SE migration: map_server

Tags: navigation, mapping, map-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to launch a map_server with a given map.yaml + bitmap, but nothing happens :

```
$ roscore &
[1] 12749
...
$ rosrun map_server map_server cave.yaml 
[ INFO] [1360845376.280636084]: Loading map from image "./bitmap/cave.png"
$ rostopic list
/rosout
/rosout_agg
$ rosservice list
/rosout/get_loggers
/rosout/set_logger_level
```

The map_server node doesn't appear to be running and doesn't show up in rqt_graph. What am I doing wrong ?

Cheers

edit: Here's the cave.yaml file.

```
image: bitmap/cave.png
resolution: 1
origin: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
occupied_thresh: 0.65
free_thresh: 0.196
negate: 0
```

edit2: ROS version is Groovy.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55192/map_server/) by [victorp](https://answers.ros.org/users/4163/victorp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 50 on 2013-02-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-02-14**:
Is you resolution really 1m/cell?

**Comment by [victorp](https://answers.ros.org/users/4163/victorp/) on 2013-02-14**:
No. I was just trying to get things working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is what happens when map_server cannot find the bitmap file. There was a typo in my yaml config file.

---

Originally posted by [victorp](https://answers.ros.org/users/4163/victorp/) with karma: 50 on 2013-02-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2